# how to use "back then"

Tags: past-tense

Are these sentences correct or not with "back then"?

> See, there were two types of cameras back then.
>
> Duke Ellington got his first New York City gig at the cotton club in Harlem. Harlem was a hot spot for up and coming music and musicians back then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are both correct usages.

For stylistic reasons, I would prefer the "back then" to be at the beginning of the second sentence, rather than at the end.

- Back then, Harlem...

I would also be inclined to hyphenate "up-and-coming"; http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up-and-coming
But again, that could be considered a matter of style, and styles change.  (Maybe *back then*, "up and coming" wasn't hyphenated!)